# Locked Solana coins have disappeared

Tags: anchor, solana-program, wallet

Solana coins were transferred from our wallet to an unknown wallet. Although the coins are locked and even we (the owners of the coins cannot do anything like that with them). Solflare technical support says that the wallet was compromised - but it is still not clear how the coins were withdrawn (even if an attacker gained access). We wrote in all available chats and technical support services, and no one could give an adequate answer. Tell me what can be done? Is it possible to contact Solana developers?

Answer (score 1):

Sad to hear. Usually locked sol can not be transfered.

Token accounts on solana can be delegated to other wallets. So they can theoretically still have access to it if you have approved it earlier.

You can check delegations here: https://famousfoxes.com/revoke
(External tool, use at your own risk)

Maybe your sol has been a delegated stake account? I think these can be transfered to another wallet. Hard to tell without more details.

If someone got access to your wallet, they were probably able to just transfer it out.